# Sum of calculated averages PowerBI

Tags: group-by, powerbi, average, dax

I'm fairly new to PowerBI, I want to calculate sum of averages as measure.

So average is perfectly fine but I couldn't manage to sum them.

```
average = AVERAGEX(SUMMARIZE(ProductionVolumeData,
                            ProductionVolumeData[ProductionOrderID],
                            MDCProductionVolumeData[MachineID],
                            "sum_volume",
                            SUM(ProductionVolumeData[Volume])),[sum_volume])
```

this formula calculates aggregates volume group by production order id and machine id and find mean.
I checked in table, it works for one ProductionOrderID but whenever I add another ProductionOrderID to table it also calculates average. What I want is to sum up averages.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi can you add some example data and the expected outcome, you may have to split it into an AVGX then a SUMX